# Как из C вызвать C++?

Tags: c++, c, функции

Есть два файла: `main.c` и `second.cpp`.

```
// main.c
extern void cxx_function();
int main() {
    cxx_function();
    return 0;
}
```

```
// second.cpp
void cxx_function() {
...
}
```

Я знаю, как действовать, если надо применить C код в C++:

```
// main.cpp
extern "C" {
extern void c_function();
}
```

```
// second.c
void c_function() {
...
}
```

Но как сделать наоборот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

1.Объявляем C++ функцию в `extern C`:

```
// second.cpp
extern "C" void cxx_function();
// затем уже объявляем саму функцию
void cxx_function() {
...
}
```

2.Объявляем обычный `extern` в C файле:

```
// main.c
extern void cxx_function();
...
```

Comment: Вполне можно объединить — `extern "C" void cxx_function() { ... };`

Comment: В общем случае, если c++ использует исключения и т.п. свойства языка, требующие специальной инициализации, то никак. Стабильно работать не будет

Comment: Просто, проблема в том, что у меня нагло перекрещиваются C++ и C функции из разных файлов..